# how to create emoji picker button inside a textbox?

Tags: css

How can I add a emoji picker button inside a text box to pick the emojis?
I can only use css and core JavaScript, I can't use jQuery. 
 I need a WhatsApp like emoji picker with which I can insert emojis inside text area.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4S8U.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what you mean by *WhatsApp like emoji picker* if you don't provide an image of what you're trying to achieve.

In any case, emojis are regular characters, so you can simply create buttons that add emojis to the text area in case the user's keyboard doesn't natively implement emoji typing. Quick example:

```js
const add = c => document.querySelector('textarea').value+=c;
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="add('')"></button>
  <button onclick="add('')"></button>
  <button onclick="add('')"></button>
  <button onclick="add('☎️')">☎️</button>
</div>

<textarea rows="5" cols="30">
Type text, or click on an emoji to add it
</textarea>
```